# How to get unique data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried `distinct` but it is not working in my case.

I have following table with data :

```
qincId   ID     lc1           lc2            Time                    SP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
963     544 22.3000526428   73.1743087769   2019-03-31 17:00:46.000  15
965     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:07.000  2
968     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:40.000  2
997     544 22.3010215759   73.1744003296   2019-03-31 17:06:11.000  15
998     544 22.3011436462   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 17:06:21.000  17
1010    544 22.3034667969   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:04.000  0
1011    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:03.000  0
1012    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:04.000  0
1028    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:11:04.000  0
1563    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 18:45:27.000  0
1564    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 18:45:28.000  0
1565    544 22.3032035828   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:45:26.000  0
1567    544 22.3032035828   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:45:28.000  0
1571    544 22.3028964996   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:46:03.000  16
1573    544 22.3023796082   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 18:46:21.000  15
1575    544 22.3021774292   73.1746444702   2019-03-31 18:46:37.000  0
1577    544 22.3019657135   73.1747665405   2019-03-31 18:46:50.000  15
1586    544 22.3009243011   73.1742477417   2019-03-31 18:47:33.000  5
1591    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:19.000  5
1592    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:28.000  5
1593    544 22.2998981476   73.1746063232   2019-03-31 18:48:29.000  4
1597    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:49:08.000  0
1611    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:51:28.000  0
1616    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:52:22.000  0
1677    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 19:03:28.000  0
```

Now I want all records with a `sp > 0` and 1st record with a `speed = 0` with same lc1 and lc2.

So basically I don't want data whose lc1 and lc2 are repeating with sp = 0

Expected output from above records:

```
qincId   ID     lc1           lc2            Time                    SP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
963     544 22.3000526428   73.1743087769   2019-03-31 17:00:46.000  15
965     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:07.000  2
968     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:40.000  2
997     544 22.3010215759   73.1744003296   2019-03-31 17:06:11.000  15
998     544 22.3011436462   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 17:06:21.000  17
1010    544 22.3034667969   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:04.000  0
1011    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:03.000  0
1565    544 22.3032035828   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:45:26.000  0
1571    544 22.3028964996   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:46:03.000  16
1573    544 22.3023796082   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 18:46:21.000  15
1575    544 22.3021774292   73.1746444702   2019-03-31 18:46:37.000  0
1577    544 22.3019657135   73.1747665405   2019-03-31 18:46:50.000  15
1586    544 22.3009243011   73.1742477417   2019-03-31 18:47:33.000  5
1591    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:19.000  5
1592    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:28.000  5
1593    544 22.2998981476   73.1746063232   2019-03-31 18:48:29.000  4
1597    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:49:08.000  0
1677    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 19:03:28.000  0
```

I have tried with *distinct* and *group by* also but i am not able to get the output.

How can I get my expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below by using union all and row_number()

```
select qincId,ID,lc1,lc2,time,sp from
(select qincId,ID,lc1,lc2,time,sp,
row_number()over(partition by lc1,lc2 order by time) rn
from table_name where sp>0
) t where t.rn=1
union all
select qincId,ID,lc1,lc2,time,sp from 
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by lc1,lc2 order by time ) rn
from table_name where sp=0
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for this solution. It is working as expected. Can you explain brief about this over and partition in existing query ?

Comment: @siddharth that part taken the min time row based on lc1 and lc2 btw if it helps mark as accepted

Comment: Can i request one more favour ?

Comment: @siddharth you can post another question if you have but at same time if need any more info you could ask here as well

Comment: Yes I am posting another question for this

Comment: Hi , Please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444077/how-to-get-calculate-time-difference-between-rows

Comment: Hi , What if i want to also match both condition sp= 0 and if sp constantly same value with same lc1 and lc2 then take its first record(order by time) ? 
I have tried to add condition sp = sp with partition sp but it is not working.
Can you guide me ?

Comment: @siddharth both means ? for same lc1,lc2 it will always min time value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191006/discussion-between-siddharth-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Comment: Please check my question in discussion.