# How to calculate time difference between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following data in a table:

```
qincId   ID     lc1           lc2            Time                    SP
963     544 22.3000526428   73.1743087769   2019-03-31 17:00:46.000  15
965     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:07.000  2
968     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:40.000  2
997     544 22.3010215759   73.1744003296   2019-03-31 17:06:11.000  15
998     544 22.3011436462   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 17:06:21.000  17
1010    544 22.3034667969   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:04.000  0
1011    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:03.000  0
1565    544 22.3032035828   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:45:26.000  0
1571    544 22.3028964996   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:46:03.000  16
1573    544 22.3023796082   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 18:46:21.000  15
1575    544 22.3021774292   73.1746444702   2019-03-31 18:46:37.000  0
1577    544 22.3019657135   73.1747665405   2019-03-31 18:46:50.000  15
1586    544 22.3009243011   73.1742477417   2019-03-31 18:47:33.000  5
1591    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:19.000  5
1592    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:28.000  5
1593    544 22.2998981476   73.1746063232   2019-03-31 18:48:29.000  4
1597    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:49:08.000  0
1677    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 19:03:28.000  0
```

Now I want to calculate time difference between to row only for sp = 0 from their next record.

Expected output:

```
qincId   ID     lc1           lc2            Time                    SP   TimeDiff (Minute)
963     544 22.3000526428   73.1743087769   2019-03-31 17:00:46.000  15     NULL
965     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:07.000  2      NULL
968     544 22.2998828888   73.1746368408   2019-03-31 17:01:40.000  2      NULL
997     544 22.3010215759   73.1744003296   2019-03-31 17:06:11.000  15     NULL
998     544 22.3011436462   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 17:06:21.000  17     NULL
1010    544 22.3034667969   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:04.000  0       0.01 
1011    544 22.3032741547   73.1747512817   2019-03-31 17:08:03.000  0       97
1565    544 22.3032035828   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:45:26.000  0       1
1571    544 22.3028964996   73.1748123169   2019-03-31 18:46:03.000  16     NULL
1573    544 22.3023796082   73.1747131348   2019-03-31 18:46:21.000  15     NULL
1575    544 22.3021774292   73.1746444702   2019-03-31 18:46:37.000  0      0.21
1577    544 22.3019657135   73.1747665405   2019-03-31 18:46:50.000  15     NULL
1586    544 22.3009243011   73.1742477417   2019-03-31 18:47:33.000  5      NULL
1591    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:19.000  5      NULL
1592    544 22.2998828888   73.1745300293   2019-03-31 18:48:28.000  5      NULL
1593    544 22.2998981476   73.1746063232   2019-03-31 18:48:29.000  4      NULL
1597    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 18:49:08.000  0      14
1677    544 22.3000450134   73.1744232178   2019-03-31 19:03:28.000  0      NULL
```

So basically I just want to calculate time difference in minute only.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by next record you mean the row that has the minimum time that is greater than the current time:

```
select t.*, 
  round(case 
    when t.sp = 0 then
      datediff(second, t.time,
        (select min(time) from tablename where time > t.time)
      ) 
    else null 
  end / 60.0, 2) timediff
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using lag() sqlserver version>=2012

```
select *, case when sp=0 then
datediff(second,time,lag(time) over(order by time)) else null end
from table_name
```

Comment: It shows error  - 'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Seems like sql-server 2008 not supporting this

Comment: sql server 2008 does not have lag function

Comment: I can't change the sql version.  I want to working for 208